# Chrome doing weird things with $_SESSION['URL'], returning the 404 page

Tags: php, google-chrome

I'm trying to figure out why this happens with Chrome, but not FF or IE.
In the following script, $this->referrer = $_SESSION['URL']; resolves to / the first time the page loads, and if I refresh the page it resolves to /404.php

```
function startSession(){
  global $database;  //The database connection
  session_name("Training");
  session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

  /* Determine if user is logged in */
  $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

  /**
   * Set guest value to users not logged in, and update
   * active guests table accordingly.
   */
  if(!$this->logged_in){
     $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
     $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
     $database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
  }
  /* Update users last active timestamp */
  else{
     $this->addLogCount($this->id);
     $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
  }

  /* Remove inactive visitors from database */
  $database->removeInactiveUsers();
  $database->removeInactiveGuests();

  /* Set referrer page */
  if(isset($_SESSION['URL'])){
     $this->referrer = $_SESSION['URL'];
  }else{
     $this->referrer = "/";
  }

  /* Set current url */
  $this->url = $_SESSION['URL'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}
```

for FF and IE, it first resolves to /, then to the address of the page that calls startSession() on refresh.
Is there something with the way that chrome handles this that I need to take into account?

$session in Chrome:

```
Session Object
(
    [id] => 
    [tracksid] => 
    [username] => Guest
    [userid] => 
    [userlevel] => 0
    [time] => 1297103371
    [logged_in] => 
    [userinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [url] => /Community/login.php
    [referrer] => /404.php
    [type] => 
    [company] => 
    [ip] => 
    [badip] => 
)
```

$session in FireFox:

```
Session Object
(
    [id] => 
    [tracksid] => 
    [username] => Guest
    [userid] => 
    [userlevel] => 0
    [time] => 1297096106
    [logged_in] => 
    [userinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [url] => /Community/login.php
    [referrer] => /Community/login.php
    [type] => 
    [company] => 
    [ip] => 
    [badip] => 
)
```

Comment: Browser has nothing to do with sessions. It only holds a session id. Could the problem be multiple requests at a time?

Comment: I've encountered a few cookie issues with Chrome, including the session cookie. It doesn't solve your problem, but it may help if you can identify whether the session cookie si correctly set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log all access to `404.php`. Also take a look in your access log and error log. That way you know who accesses which URL it at which time (I guess invalid URLs are handled by `404.php`). I suspect some kind of web accelerator that tries to download a file that does not exist, or the favicon is not specified in the HTML, so the browser tries to guess and download a standard one.

Comment: So this is a somewhat new site, and we hadn't setup a favicon at all yet. I copied one up, and the problem went away... Granted, the favicon isn't showing up in the address bar yet, but at least I don't get the 404 page as the referrer anymore. Thanks for the tip.